# indexOf keeps returning -1 Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop, indexof

For the life me of I can't figure out why indexOf cant find the number in the array. It keeps returning -1. My goal is to ban a noun and put it into a ban array list, the list must be unique. So each element in the array must be different. Since I keep getting -1, my while loop is never executing.

Can anyone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong!

```
if( useA < 101 && totalAs < 5){
    article1Num = 4; // A
    noun1Num = [Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];  
//^^^ random number to try use

//-------- 
    // Code to check if number is ban
    alert("Test Noun1Num is " + noun1Num);
    alert(bannedNounsTest.indexOf(noun1Num));   
//^^^^ITS ALWAYS -1 !!!!!!! EVEN if there is a match!
    while (bannedNounsTest.indexOf(parseInt(noun1Num)) >= 0 ) {   
// ^^^searching the value of the current noun in ban, -1 if none
        alert("In Loop and noun1Num is " + noun1Num);
        noun1Num = [Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];  
// ^^looking for new number not in index while
    }

//----------

bannedNounsTest.push(noun1Num); // put in ban list
    totalAs++;
```

Comment: Your "random number" is actually an array.

Comment: Oh wow, I wasted over 5 hours and it's because I had noun1Num as an array. You just saved me an extra who know hours. My question when the banned array does the indexOf the noun array (I fixed it thanks to you), why does it give -1?

Comment: Once again thanks brianvaughn

Comment: It gives a -1 because that's what indexOf returns when it can't find a match. (And it can't, since you're searching for a matching array vs a number)

Comment: @brianvaughn Why didn't you post that as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives a -1 because that's what `indexOf` returns when it can't find a match. (And it can't, since you're searching for a matching array vs a number)

What you want is...

```
noun1Num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
```